# How to dynamically display cards in a grid

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-grid

I am designing the UI for a web app which will dynamically display data from my database in form of cards and will be arranged in a grid. 
 For testing purposes I have put two cards , one after the other , however, only the first one is being displayed. 
How can I get them to be displayed in a 3 column row after which if there are more than 3, they overflow to the next row dynamically?

```
<div class="container_grid">


                <div class="product-card" style="margin: 1rem">
                    <div class="product-front">
                        <div class="shadow"></div>
                        <img src="https://veenaazmanov.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Chocolate-Birthday-Cake5-500x500.jpg" alt="" />
                        <div class="image_overlay"></div>
                        <div class="view-details">View details</div>
                        <div class="stats">         
                            <div class="stats-container">
                                <span class="product_price">Ksh.500</span>
                                <span class="product_name">Chocolate Cake</span>    
                                <p>Tasty cake</p>                                            

                                <div class="product-options">
                                <strong>Available in</strong>
                                <span>1kg, 2kg, 3kg, 4kg, 5kg</span>
                                <button class="btn">Add To Cart</button>
                                 <!-- <div class="cart_btn"><p>Add to Cart</p></div> -->
                            </div>                       
                            </div>                         
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                   </div>


            <div class="product-card" style="margin: 1rem">
                <div class="product-front">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <img src="https://veenaazmanov.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Chocolate-Birthday-Cake5-500x500.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="image_overlay"></div>
                    <div class="view-details">View details</div>
                    <div class="stats">         
                        <div class="stats-container">
                            <span class="product_price">Ksh.500</span>
                            <span class="product_name">Chocolate Cake</span>    
                            <p>Tasty cake</p>                                            

                            <div class="product-options">
                            <strong>Available in</strong>
                            <span>1kg, 2kg, 3kg, 4kg, 5kg</span>
                            <button class="btn">Add To Cart</button>

                        </div>                       
                        </div>                         
                    </div>

                 </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Link to the full JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5yoerguh/3/
 
 What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are being displayed if you check the console both `div class='product-card'` is there.
The problem is in the css your class .propduct-card is displayed with position:absolute;

```
    .product-card {
    width: 20rem;
    max-width: 95%;
    width: 325px;
    height: 490px;
 --> take this out   /* position: absolute; */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now you will see both items

Comment: You will need to check your css, on hover of the product card will also not work. product-card need to be relative and then on hover when it becomes active to overlay can be position absolute to show details... At the moment the .product-card is asolute and everything is on top of each other.

Comment: I just noticed that while yes the cards are being displayed, the hover is making everything glitch

Comment: I've fiddled around with the positioning and I seem to have stabilized it. Thank you alot

Comment: You are welcome. Yes you will just need to check the css and make sure about your positioning of elements. Also make use of the console to check your html and css makes it much easier. If you are using Chrome right click choose inspec and dock that sucker somewhere, i put mine on the second screen, and most of the time i will fix in console html and css and then copy and paste into the .css file. Just a personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll do that asap